# Async Function returns Promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I don't understand why i get `Promise { <pending> }` since i used async/await

this is my code

```
const  fetch = require("node-fetch")

function getRandomPokemon() {
    var pokemonID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 851);
    console.log("The Pokemon Id is " + pokemonID);
    return pokemonID
}

async function getJSON() {
    let response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+ pokemonID);
    var json = await response.json
}

var pokemonID = getRandomPokemon()
var json = getJSON()
console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise - always.  Using `await` inside an `async` function suspends the execution of that function until the promise you are awaiting resolves or rejects, but an `async` function is not blocking to the outside world.  An `await` does not suspend execution of the whole js interpreter.

**At the point of the first `await`** in the `async` function **your function returns a promise back to the caller and the caller continues to execute**.  That promise is then resolved or rejects when the function eventually completes its work sometime in the future.

> I don't understand why i get Promise {  } since i used async/await

Because all `async` functions return a promise.

---

There are numerous issues in your code:

1. Your `getJSON()` function has no return value.  That means that the promise it returns resolves to `undefined` so there's not way to communicate back its value.
2. `await response.json` needs to be `await response.json()`.
3. `pokemonID` should be passed as an argument, not just stuffed into a higher scoped variable.
4. When calling `getJSON()`, you have to use `.then()` or `await` on it to get the resolved value from the returned promise.

You may also notice that your `getJSON()` function has no return value.  That means that the promise it returns also resolves to `undefined`.  And, `await response.json` needs to be `await response.json()`.

Your code needs to be more like this:

```
async function getJSON(id) {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+ id);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
}

const pokemonID = getRandomPokemon();
getJSON(pokemonID).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: @BRUH - Please make sure to see my latest edits for a summary of things I changed and why.

Answer (score 5):

Three problems:

1. `getJSON()` doesn't return anything. It needs to end with `return json;`.
2. Declaring a function `async` makes it return a promise. If you want to get the return value directly rather than a promise, you have to call it with `await getJSON()`. You can only do that if you're calling it from another async function.
3. You need to call `response.json`: `var json = response.json();`

Answer (score -1):

`response.json` should be a function.

On your `getJSON` function definition, you are doing `await response.json`.
Change it to `await response.json()`.

*Notice the parenthesis after json()*.

Since the `getJSON` function returns promise, you have to await the response

On your second last line, add `var json = await getJSON();`

furthermore, in order to use `await`, you must wrap your code in an async function

*Wrap your last and second-last line in an async function*

```js
async function resolveJSON(){
    var json = await getJSON(); // waits for the promise to fulfill
    console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: still gives promise pending

Comment: yeah, you have to then await that function to resolve.
On your second-last line, `await` the `getJSON` function.

`var json = await getJSON()`

Comment: @BRUH I have edited my answer.
Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65913058/11416157)

Answer (score -1):

Just a few changes

1. Add the return statement to the getJSON() function
2. Use the .json() function to get the json from the response in the getJSON()
3. One way to handle a promise is to use .then(). You could also use await but make sure that it's scoped inside an await block.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function getRandomPokemon() {
  var pokemonID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 851);
  console.log('The Pokemon Id is ' + pokemonID);
  return pokemonID;
}

async function getJSON() {
  let response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokemonID);
  var json = await response.json();
  return json
}

var pokemonID = getRandomPokemon();
getJSON().then((json) => {
  console.log(json);
});
```